# How to check one single array value into another multiple value?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Hello Developer I am trying to check one single array into multiple array value and My exact requirement is the value of one array should be check in each indexes of second array and replace if same otherwise append it in new array.

My Two array was like this:-
One array:-

```
$array1 = array(
    "extension_date" => "2017-05-19",
    "extended_date" => "2017-05-27"
);
```

Second Array:-

```
$array2 = array(
    0 => array(
        "extension_date" => "2017-05-19",
        "extended_date" => "2017-05-27"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "extension_date" => "2017-05-31",
        "extended_date" => "2017-05-31"
    ),
);
```

I am try it from yesterday but it's not be succeed so please help me to solve out this issue.

Comment: use foreach() with == or === operator

Comment: show your expected out put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are using `array_search` if needle doesn't exist then we add that in array.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/805585)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$array1 = array(
    "extension_date" => "2017-05-19",
    "extended_date" => "2017-05-27"
);
$array2 = array(
    0 => array(
        "extension_date" => "2017-05-19",
        "extended_date" => "2017-05-27"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "extension_date" => "2017-05-31",
        "extended_date" => "2017-05-31"
    ),
);

if(array_search($array1, $array2)===false)
{
    $array2[]=$array1;
}
print_r($array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `array_search` and `array_push`. You don't need to replace if you find the search array in the main array since it's the exact same thing.

```
$search = [
    "extension_date" => "2017-05-19",
    "extended_date" => "2017-05-27"
];

$data = [
    [
        "extension_date" => "2017-05-19",
        "extended_date" => "2017-05-27"
    ],
    [
        "extension_date" => "2017-05-31",
        "extended_date" => "2017-05-31"
    ]
];

if (array_search($search, $data) === false) {
    array_push($data, $search);
}

// $data contains $search if it's missing
```

Answer (score 0):

Inputs:

```
$array1 = array(
    "extension_date" => "2017-05-19",
    "extended_date" => "2017-05-27"
);
$array2 = array(
    array(
        "extension_date" => "2017-05-19",
        "extended_date" => "2017-05-27"
    ),
    array(
        "extension_date" => "2017-05-31",
        "extended_date" => "2017-05-31"
    ),
);
```

Method:

```
if(!in_array($array1,$array2)){
    $array2[]=$array1;
}
```

Since you are only checking to see if the subarray exists and you don't care about its key, it doesn't make sense to use `array_search()`.  `in_array()` was specifically designed to return true false -- so use it!

`var_export($array2)` output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'extension_date' => '2017-05-19',
    'extended_date' => '2017-05-27',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'extension_date' => '2017-05-31',
    'extended_date' => '2017-05-31',
  ),
)
```